# How do I add a vote to my database in a form?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

alright,The problem is I can't get my database to add a vote to it on the votes page or my database after an individual on the previous page clicks submit for there vote to a question. I've tried things like `$vote = $vote + 1` in my PHP code and then displaying it with SQL through `$command` but that doesn't work and many other things I've tried like making a variable = 1 ($avote = 1) so I'm kinda stuck, someone told me that I can just add 1 by doing this - 
`$votes = $row['Votes' . $i] + 1;` and then I'd have to display it under somehow but I couldn't figure it out, here's my code within my page to retrieve the information and add it to my database and page (I've taken out unneccesary HTML table tags for a clearer view):

```
        // if $row is false, then the pollid must have been wrong
        if ($row) {
            // display the poll
            echo '<h1>' . $row['Title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<p><b>' . $row['Question'] . '</b></p>';

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
                $answer = $row['Answer' . $i];
                $votes = $row['Votes' . $i];
                $avote = 1;
                $command = "UPDATE FROM polls SET $answer WHERE $answer='$answer+$avote'";

                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($command);
                $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['Votes']));
```

If my friend is right about the `$votes = $row['Votes' . $i] + 1`; can someone please let me know how I'd display it within my `$command` SQL code:
`$command = "UPDATE FROM polls SET $answer WHERE $answer='$answer+$avote'";`

Please and Thank you for any insights.

Comment: Could you take the time to clear up your post a bit? Also, only include the relevant lines of code and be very clear on what you're stuck on. It's all a bit confusing.

Comment: alright i'll edit it right now

Comment: You've tagged two different database platforms; Microsoft's SQL Server and MySQL. Which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get error messages?

It sounds like you're trying to show the results of a poll (after the user submits their own vote), but you're having trouble retrieving the results of the poll. Since the poll results need to persist across users and sessions, you have to store it somewhere. I guess that's what `$answer` is in your database?

Your `UPDATE` query is a bit broken. First, you should make sure it works properly without the variables, I like to go the the command line client or a graphical tool like phpMyAdmin. It might look more like:

```
UPDATE polls SET result = result + 1 WHERE poll_id = 1;
```

Where `poll` is your table and `result` and `poll_id` are columns in your table.

It appears as if you're trying to ask the user multiple questions, so you would have a different `poll_id` for each one, and use a hidden form field to get the value for the `poll_id`. You appear to be using the `$row` array for that now, but it seems fragile and it won't scale as you build more poll options (well, technically it will scale up, but you won't ever be able to remove a question or get rid of old polls.

You seem to be using PDO (since the "object oriented style" mysqli `execute` takes a void parameter and none of the PHP libraries that speak to SQL Server seem to have that exact syntax), but then I would expect your `prepare` statement to have question marks for the variables rather than direct substitution. See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for details if you're unclear about the proper syntax, but hopefully you've already been through that before coming here.

Once you get those issues cleaned up, if you have further problems it should be a bit easier to trace through what's going on.